# R: Table to vector and remove last column

Tags: r

I have multiple df like this:

```
> atl
         V1      V2      V3      V4 V5
1 583000063 4993685 3596095 1792216 NA

> can
         V1      V2      V3      V4      V5      V6      V7 V8
1 497237885 6059255 3890358 1884078 1470844 1012488 1803499 NA
```

I created them using this loop:

```
my.files <- list.files(path="SFS/", pattern = ".sfs")
for (i in 1:(length(my.files))){
  my.pop <- c("atl", "can","dac_adm1","dac_Jud","dac_ME_adm1")
  cur.file <- read.table(file = paste0("SFS/", my.files[i]), sep = " ")
  my.name <- my.pop[i]
  assign(paste(my.name), cur.file)
}
```

But I would like these to be vectors, and not df. I don't manage to do that, tried a few stuff (including as.vector) but failed.

I would also like to have the final NA removed.

Once this is done, my vectors atl and can will be of length 4 and 7 respectively.

If this length is n, then I also want to add 0s to the vector so that it final length would  be 2*(n-1)-1.

So for atl, I should have a final length with the 0s of 2*(4-1)-1=5 and for can: 2*(7-1)-1=11.

So basically, atl and can should look like this:

```
> atl
[1] 583000063   4993685   3596095   1792216         0
> can
 [1] 497237885   6059255   3890358   1884078   1470844   1012488   1803499         0         0         0         0
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why do you have `atl` of length 5 and `can` of length 11? How is that `2n-1` ? What is `n` ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ronak! 
n is the length of the vector (once NA is removed)
and basically, I want to add 0 to the vector so that it reaches the length 2n-1.

Comment: But you show `alt` of length 5 shouldn't it be of length 7 then ? (2 * 4 - 1) and `can` of length 13 similarly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have already read your data as dataframe, we can convert the dataframe to vector.

```
my.pop <- c("atl", "can","dac_adm1","dac_Jud","dac_ME_adm1")

new_data <- lapply(mget(my.pop), function(x) {
                x <- unname(na.omit(unlist(x)))
                x <- x[1:(2 * (length(x) - 1) - 1)]
                x[is.na(x)] <- 0
                return(x)
              })
```

`new_data` has list of vectors in them. Usually, it is better to keep data in a list because it is easier to manage and avoids cluttering the global environment. However, if you want them as separate vectors you can use `list2env`.

```
list2env(new_data, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak! It's exactly what I needed to do! It will be sooo convenient!!! The function you wrote is using several stuff I was not aware off so I'll try to remember those for next time ;-)